# ImportError 'mach-o, but wrong architecture' on PyCharm when trying to import pygame

Tags: python, pygame, importerror

I am trying to import pygame for an adventure game project in PyCharm. However, when I try to run the main file, this error appears:

```
  
File "/Users/########/PycharmProjects/adventure game /main.py", line 1, in <module>
    import pygame
  
File "/Users/########/Library/Python/3.10/lib/python/site-packages/pygame/__init__.py", line 83, in <module>
    from pygame.base import *  # pylint: disable=wildcard-import; lgtm[py/polluting-import]

ImportError: 
dlopen(/Users/########/Library/Python/3.10/lib/python/site-packages/pygame/base.cpython-310-darwin.so, 2): no suitable image found.  Did find:
    /Users/########/Library/Python/3.10/lib/python/site-packages/pygame/base.cpython-310-darwin.so: mach-o, but wrong architecture
    /Users/########/Library/Python/3.10/lib/python/site-packages/pygame/base.cpython-310-darwin.so: mach-o, but wrong architecture
```

I have used pygame before on IDLE and it works just fine. On PyCharm I use a Python 3.10 interpreter "/usr/local/bin/python3", with a virtual environment. The Python versions I have are 2.7.16 and 3.10.5, but I cannot use sudo commands to remove the older version. Why can I import pygame on IDLE but not PyCharm, and how can I fix this error?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have installed pygame first. When downloading python, did you make sure to enable "ADD PYTHON TO PATH"? If so, enter this into your command prompt:

```
pip install pygame
```

If that doesn't work:

```
pip3 install pygame
```

If that doesn't work:

```
python -m pip install pygame
```

If none of these work, try reinstalling python and make sure to enable "ADD PYTHON TO PATH" when installing. Once installed, try the commands above. This error may be caused by something other than pygame's installation, but I suspect it is because python was installed incorrectly.